# How to pass a callback function in renderCell columns for Material UI X Datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to hook into a simple toast hook and display a message when a button. I want to display a toast in the parent component I have my Data grid in when a button is clicked and the redux action is successful.

Is it possible to pass a callback to use a hook in a parent component from within the data grid?

Code for the column in question:

```js
const columns = [{
  field: 'actions',
  headerName: 'Actions',
  renderCell: (params) => {
      const { row } = params;

      const onClickResetPassword = (e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          store.dispatch(Users.sendPasswordResetEmail(row.uuid));
          // callback here, open toast 
      };

      return (
        <div className = "d-flex">
            <Tooltip title = "Send Password Reset Email">
                <IconButton onClick = { onClickResetPassword } color = "primary">
                    <VpnKey fontSize = "small"/>
                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
        </div>
      );
  },
}]
```

Parent Component

```js
export default function FilteringDataGrid() {
  const [toastElement, openToast] = useToast();

  // Callback for toast
  const toastCallback = (message) => { 
    openToast(message);
  };

  return ( 
    <Box sx={{ width: '95%' }}>
      <DataGrid components={{ Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar }}
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        autoHeight
        autoSizeColumns
        rowHeight={48}
        editMode="row"
        pageSize={10}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditCommit}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]}  
      />
      {toastElement}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a custom Function as a row Element and then trigger it within `renderCell`:

```
const columns = [{
  field: 'actions',
  headerName: 'Actions',
  renderCell: (params) => {
      const { row } = params;

      const onClickResetPassword = (e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
          store.dispatch(Users.sendPasswordResetEmail(row.uuid));
          // callback here, open toast 
          row.openToast("This will be toast Message");
      };

      return (
        <div className = "d-flex">
            <Tooltip title = "Send Password Reset Email">
                <IconButton onClick = { onClickResetPassword } color = "primary">
                    <VpnKey fontSize = "small"/>
                </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
        </div>
      );
  },
}]
```

I don't see from where you have passed the rows, but assuming that they're passed correctly, this should work:

```
export default function FilteringDataGrid() {
  const [toastElement, openToast] = useToast();

  // Callback for toast
  const toastCallback = (message) => { 
    openToast(message);
  };

   //Modify rows here:
   const modifiedRows = rows.map(element => {
    return {
    ...element,
    openToast: toastCallback
    };
   });

  return ( 
    <Box sx={{ width: '95%' }}>
      <DataGrid components={{ Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar }}
        rows={modifiedRows}
        columns={columns}
        autoHeight
        autoSizeColumns
        rowHeight={48}
        editMode="row"
        pageSize={10}
        onRowEditStop={handleRowEditCommit}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]}  
      />
      {toastElement}
    </Box>
  );
}
```